# How to design an override-safe factory method that allows subclasses to return covariant types?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, covariance

I have a parent class that is designed to be const-safe, so I want to create "factory" methods that will return an altered version of itself in a newly constructed object. I want to be able to return by value and avoid heap allocation, similar in function to `std::string::substr`. This works fine in the parent class, but how to I allow a subclass to return override this method to return a covariant type, preferably without pointers or references?

I have a `Point` class that is provided to me that represents a 2D position:

```
class Point
{
    double x, y;

public:
    Point() : Point(0, 0)
    { }

    Point(double xpos, double ypos) : x{xpos}, y{ypos}
    { }

    double get_x() const { return x; }
    double get_y() const { return y; }

    virtual Point flip_x() const
    {
        return Point{x, -y};
    }

    virtual Point flip_y() const
    {
        return Point{-x, y};
    }
    ...
};
```

Notice that `flip_x` and `flip_y` are factory methods that return a new flipped `Point` object by value. This allows me to do something like `const Point flipped = p.flip_x()` without modifying the contents of `const Point p`.

I am implementing a subclass to `Point` called `Point3D` that supports an additional z depth coordinate. I want to be able to override these flip functions to return a `Point3D` instead, in order to be consistent with the return type of `flip_z`:

```
class Point3D : public Point
{
    double z;

public:
    Point3D() : Point3D(0, 0, 0)
    { }

    Point3D(double xpos, double ypos, double zpos)
    : Point(xpos, ypos), z{zpos}
    { }

    double get_z() const { return z; }

    // *** ERROR: return type is not covariant ***
    Point3D flip_x() const override
    {
        return Point3D{get_x(), -get_y(), -z};
    }

    // *** ERROR: return type is not covariant ***
    Point3D flip_y() const override
    {
        return Point3D{-get_x(), get_y(), -z};
    }
    
    Point3D flip_z() const
    {
        return Point3D{-get_x(), -get_y(), z};
    }
    ...
};
```

So these errors tell me that the return types are not covariant with the parent methods. As far as I can tell, my only options for using covariant returns are to use references or pointers. I cannot return a reference or pointer to a local variable, and using `new` to return a heap allocated `Point` adds unnecessary complexity to memory management. How can I achieve the effect of returning by value/static binding when returning a covariant type, so that the following is still valid:

```
const Point p{2, 2};
const Point flipped = p.flip_x();     // (2, -2)
const Point3D p3{2, 2, 2};
const Point3D flipped3 = p3.flip_x(); // (2, -2, -2)
```

Is this possible using this parent class and within these limitations, or will I have to switch to pointers & heap allocation?

Comment: This has nothing to do with [factory methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Comment: Okay reading this I now understand this isn't a factory method. What's the best term to describe this kind of method that returns an mutated version of itself as a newly constructed object?

Comment: There is no special term for this AFAICT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove virtual, you might do:

```
class Point
{
    double x, y;

public:
    Point() : Point(0, 0) { }
    Point(double xpos, double ypos) : x{xpos}, y{ypos} { }

    double get_x() const { return x; }
    double get_y() const { return y; }

    Point flip_x() const { return Point{x, -y}; }
    Point flip_y() const { return Point{-x, y}; }
    // ...
};

class Point3D : public Point
{
    double z;

public:
    Point3D() : Point3D(0, 0, 0) { }
    Point3D(double xpos, double ypos, double zpos) : Point(xpos, ypos), z{zpos}     {}

    double get_z() const { return z; }

    // hides parent ones
    Point3D flip_x() const { return Point3D{get_x(), -get_y(), -z}; }
    Point3D flip_y() const { return Point3D{-get_x(), get_y(), -z}; }
    
    Point3D flip_z() const { return Point3D{-get_x(), -get_y(), z}; }
    ///...
};
```

Comment: Thank you! This is definitely the easiest solution for this current design, and answers my question about covariant returns. but I think I agree with @user1806566 that the Point class needs to be redesigned as a template class to support extra coordinates!

Comment: Covariant return types are only applicable to overriden virtual functions. Non-virtual functions are not overriden and have unrelated return types, rather than covariant return types.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think `Point3D` should be derived from `Point` since a 3D point isn't a specialization of the concept of 2D point.

If you had two different classes, you wouldn't have this problem.

If you wanted to generate those classes from the same source, you could do something like:

```
template <size_t N>
class Point {
   std::array< double, N > dims;

public:
   ...
};
```

and then you'd have a common implementation for points of any size.  You wouldn't have accessors called `x`, `y`, and `z`, but you could use numeric indices to specify components.

Comment: You can even have `double get_z() const requires (N > 2) { return dims[2]; }` (C++20)

Comment: I think this is by far the best answer in terms of advice for the design structure that I have currently. Templated Point class takes away the inheritance complexity to fully support what I need and even more.